# Debugging Angular JS provider error for minified files only

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging, minify, bundling-and-minification

I am getting below error after the files have been minified -

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/unpr?p0=aProvider%20%3C-%20a%20%3C-%20%24exceptionHandler%20%3C-%20%24rootScope%20%3C-%20%24translate
```

What have I checked -
All the dependencies are added in the array format.
There are no typos.

My question - 
How to catch the exact file/point which is causing the error.
From the error above, does it mean 'rootScope' or 'translate' are the culprits?

Comment: You can use strict DI mode in your development code to catch what `a` stands for.

Comment: Is there any other way other than that? since for now i cannot make any changes in that part of the code.

Comment: Another option is to reverse-engineer your minified code to detect what is that `a` service. You can use code beautifier for that.